# Set column status based on another dataframe column value pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have two pyspark dataframes as below

main_df:

```
cat1 cat2 cat3
 a    9     e
 b    3     f
 c    11    g
 d    6     h
```

support_df:

```
cat value1 value2
cat1   1      2
cat1   3      4
cat1   5      6
cat1   7      8
cat2   1      2
cat2   3      4
cat2   5      6
cat2   7      8
```

I need to check if value in `main_df: cat2` matches with either value in `support_df: value1` or `support_df: value2` when the `cat` column is `cat2`.

In the above example, when `cat` == `cat2`, there are four rows in support_df. and the values from `main_df` are (`9, 3, 11, 6`). Out of which only 3 and 6 matches in `value1` and `value2`

I would like to have a result dataframe as below

```
cat1 cat2 cat3 cat2_status
 a    9     e    NotMatched
 b    3     f    Matched
 c    11    g    NotMatched
 d    6     h    Matched
```

Can someone help on how to achieve this using pyspark (do we need to write a user-defined function or it can be done using joins )?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use left join and `when` expression to create new column `cat2_status` if there is any match on `support_df`:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F


result = main_df.alias("main").join(
    support_df.alias("supp"),
    (F.col("supp.cat") == "cat2") &
    ((F.col("main.cat2") == F.col("supp.value1")) |
     (F.col("main.cat2") == F.col("supp.value2"))),
    "left"
).select(
    "main.*",
    F.when(
        F.col("supp.cat").isNotNull(), "Matched"
    ).otherwise("NotMatched").alias("cat2_status")
)

result.show()

#+----+----+----+-----------+
#|cat1|cat2|cat3|cat2_status|
#+----+----+----+-----------+
#|   a|   9|   e| NotMatched|
#|   b|   3|   f|    Matched|
#|   c|  11|   g| NotMatched|
#|   d|   6|   h|    Matched|
#+----+----+----+-----------+
```